# Element inside div with clip-path doesn't work with absolute position

Tags: html, css, css-position, polygon, clip-path

I am trying to add a tooltip in a div which has `clip-path: polygon`. The problem is that I can't give `position: absolute` to my tooltip (to be above the parent div). When parent div doesn't have a clip-path regule everything works fine.

Something like that:

```
<div>
<div class="house">
  <div class="tooltip">
   ITEM 1
   </div>
 </div>
</div>


.house {
 height: 91px;
 left: 72px;
 top: 81px;
 width: 57px;
 background-color: #fe0000;
}

.tooltip {
  background-color: #aaa;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Adding "position: relative;" to ".house" should solve it.

Position absolute in CSS relates to the first parent element where the position is not static. The default value in CSS for position is Static, that's why it probably does not work for you.

The fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/anebkb42/2/

```
.house {
  height: 91px;
  left: 72px;
  top: 81px;
  width: 57px;
  background-color: #fe0000;
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip {
  background-color: #aaa;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I put wrong code. Problem is with clip-path: https://jsfiddle.net/hw1aq0pq/

Comment: So you want the child element to not be affected by the clip-path, right? Does creating a container (like this: https://jsfiddle.net/yz7jrn4v/ ) solves your issue? Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Thanks for idea, I will try this!